# Aligning multiple images with different spatial resolutions

Tags: overlay, satellite, resampling, esri-grid-format

I am using 2 different satellite images that have different spatial resolutions. One of them has 1 degree and other has 0.25 degree resolution. I want to subtract one image from another. So I should resample 0.25 to 1 degree resolution. When I do that, it is resampled to 1 degree but not overlay with other image. It is shifting below. [image]Am I doing something wrong ? The both data have same projections and datum.

Comment: Use 1 degree as snap raster and cell size. No need to resample when subtract.

Comment: Thanks for your help FelixIP but I want to overlay these two data. I now think that one of them may require geometric correction to overlay